# Cannot use MvcHtmlString/IHtmlString with RazorEngine

Tags: c#, nunit, razorengine

I just started playing around with the RazorEngine and I'm stumbling when using a static helper method. It just produces an MvcHtmlString/IHtmlString for the template. When calling Razor.Parse(...) I get

```
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException : Unable to compile template. 
Der Typ 'System.Web.IHtmlString' ist in einer nicht referenzierten Assembly definiert. (not referenced)
Fügen Sie einen Verweis auf die Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' hinzu.
```

I have added references to `System.Web`, `System.Web.Mvc`, `System.Web.WebPages`. Also tried to add them to the *cshtml* (`@using System.Web`, `@using System.Web.Mvc`). 
But `@using System.Web.Mvc` results in `.Mvc` is not available in `System.Web`?!

I'm trying to build the templates in **NUnit** Tests currently.

Comment: Okay, it is working if I'm creating a `MvcHtmlString` in code, before trying to `Parse` a Template. So maybe one has to use something from the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace in C# code before using it in the Razor template?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, have you found a solution ? Thanks

Comment: Someone answered me here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23496144/1875786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RazorEngine has a class CompilerServicesUtility. This is responsible for loading and making assemblies available when your view is compiled. It by default returns all assemblies loaded in the current AppDomain.

Its bit unintuitive for someone looking at the code, but one way to make sure that your Razor view compiles and you can use MvcHtmlString is to load the System.Web and System.Web.Mvc assemblies into the current AppDomain using AppDomain.Current.Load("") prior to executing/ compiling your view.

Comment: Being inexperienced with application domain stuff. I have been struggling for 5 hours to figure that out. That's what happens when you have a great library with a terrible documentation! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

An old question. @Gopal has the correct answer. As well as adding the following code, I had to set the reference to System.Web to copy local.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("System.Web");
```